# ¿Como hago que el archivo de PHP haga que AJAX haga fail?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Buenas.
Estoy intentando hacer un programa que mire si la contraseña de un formulario está en un archivo.txt.

El archivo está línea por línea de esta manera:

> 000
> 010
> 001
> ...

Sigue así con muchísimas contraseñas pero es para que os hagais a la idea.
Mí *código* de **AJAX** donde  $("#pass" sería donde está la contraseña):

```
    $("#pass").on("change",function(){
        var data = $("#pass");
        var request = $.ajax({
            url:'egiaztatuPosta.php',
            data: data,
            dataType:'html'
        });
        request.done(function(data){
            echo("No está dentro");
        });
        request.fail(function(data){
            echo("Está dentro");
        });
    });
```

Mí código **PHP**:

```
$pasahitzak = fopen('../DATUAK/toppasswords1.txt','r');
$aurk=false;
$zenb=0;
while($linea = fgets($pasahitzak)){
    $aux[] = $linea;
     echo "<script>console.log( 'Pasahitza: " . "$_REQUEST[pasahitza]" . "' );</script>\n";
     echo "<script>console.log( 'Lerroa: " . $linea . "' );</script>\n";
    if("$_REQUEST[pasahitza]"==$linea){
        $aurk=true;
    }
    echo "<script>console.log( 'Finala: " . $ald . "' );</script>";
}

fclose($pasahitzak);
```

Lo que quiero saber es si hay algún modo de que el AJAX haga la función de fail cuando $aurk es igual a true($aurk=true).
Creo que con esos dos cachos de código es suficiente para exponer mí duda. Si necesitáis algo más de código porque no es suficiente ponedlo en los comentarios.
 No he encontrado nada útil y por eso pregunto.Saludos.

Comment: Pero atención, `fail` es para manejar los fallos de código, por ejemplo, una url de archivo incorrecta, un error en el código del PHP, etc. Todas las peticiones que corran con normalidad o con éxito (`done`), tienes que manejarlas dentro de `done`. Lo digo porque en el planteamiento original de tu pregunta parecería que crees que `fail` es para cuestiones que pertenecen a la lógica de tu programa. El código sólo entrará en `fail` cuando ocurra algún error en el flujo de la petición.

Comment: Imaginaba algo así, pero no se me había ocurrido otra manera de hacerlo. Gracias por la información. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El data es lo que regresas del php, por lo que sí haces

```
$pasahitzak = fopen('../DATUAK/toppasswords1.txt','r');
$aurk=false;
$zenb=0;
while($linea = fgets($pasahitzak)){
    $aux[] = $linea;
     echo "<script>console.log( 'Pasahitza: " . "$_REQUEST[pasahitza]" . "' );</script>\n";
     echo "<script>console.log( 'Lerroa: " . $linea . "' );</script>\n";
    if("$_REQUEST[pasahitza]"==$linea){
        echo "true";
    }
    echo "false";
}

fclose($pasahitzak);
```

Al hacer el callback done, debera traerlo en el data

```
 request.done(function(data){
    if(data == true) {
        //aquí va tu código
     } else {
       //aquí va si no
     }


 });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona bien